# Does Brave browser have ability to sync bookmarks like firefox login mechanism?

Tags: firefox, browser, bookmarks

I am using Firefox for a long time. But it causes high CPU temperature. Sometimes even it raises to 150-200 %.But Brave causing less CPU usage.

I  would like to import all the bookmarks in Firefox to the Brave. Is there any chance to sync bookmarks from one device to other just like Firefox does by adding account and sign in it sync everything?

Comment: For Firefox (Version 47+) you can go to `about:performance` to see an exact breakdown of what's causing the CPU usage, probably it's a badly written extension.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the FAQ](https://brave.com/FAQ.html):

> #### 16. What kind of data is stored in the Brave Vault? Can users access it?
>
> The vault generates a UUID upon connection from your first Brave
>   install on a laptop or smartphone. This UUID will be shared across
>   devices so you can pair devices without a login system, using just a
>   QR code or similar. The browser supplies a public key for
>   authentication of this anonymous identity. Everything else inside the
>   vault is encrypted by a browser-generated key that we have no access
>   to.
>
> The Brave Vault can hold information that users would like to sync
>   across devices such as bookmarks, passwords, etc. -- but only with
>   user permission to sync this data. It also holds the combined,
>   anonymized cross-device browser history captured by the browser. The
>   user can access any of this information and has complete control over
>   what is stored. The vault is not connected to any PII, email,
>   username, etc.

Comment: ....so how do you actually get access to your UUID from a particular device? "using just a QR code or similar" sounds like a statement about an API, not a user-facing feature.

Comment: @KyleStrand Under Preferences > Sync, click on the orange button that says "Sync a new device..." This will give you the code or QR code.